# Gmail app crashes when opening from another app intent

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I have a registration screen and once a user is finished registering, they are given an alert to check their mail and it redirects them to gmail. However, gmail crashes and it redirects back to the login screen of my app. Was the app redirect implemented correctly?

```
//method that opens check email alert

public void showDialogForRegistrationSuccess(final Activity activity, String msg) {
    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(activity);
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    dialog.setCancelable(false);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog_for_exception);

    TextView text = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.text_dialog);

    text.setText(Html.fromHtml(msg));

    Button dialogButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btn_dialog_ok);

    dialogButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            dialog.dismiss();
            sendEmail();
            finish();

        }
    });
    dialog.show();

}
/**Method that opens email client*/
public void sendEmail() {
    final Intent emailLauncher = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    emailLauncher.setType("message/rfc822");

    try {
        startActivity(emailLauncher);
        finish();

    } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
        System.out.println("not working");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you're calling `finish()` twice. Remove it from your `sendEmail()` method.

Second, since you're not trying to send an email through your app, change your `sendEmail()` method to:

```
public void sendEmail() {
    Intent emailLauncher = Intent.makeMainSelectorActivity(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, Intent.CATEGORY_APP_EMAIL);
    emailLauncher.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(emailLauncher);
}
```

Read more about it here [on the docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#CATEGORY_APP_EMAIL).

Answer (score 2):

Use this

```
public void sendEmail(){
Intent mailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
mailIntent.setClassName("com.google.android.gm","com.google.android.gm.ConversationListActivity");
startActivity(mailClient);
}
```

Comment: This is not a good idea since the package name can change, and it's not documented.

Comment: You can use try catch block if package name changes, which is very unlikely.

Comment: Still a nasty hack. If your app is published on the play store and some day they decide to change the package name, your users will have to wait for an update to make the app work again. That'll probably lead to a lot of uninstalls.

Comment: The proper way to do this is with the appropriate URI or selector